# iPad: Remove app installed by other user

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-appstore

I have an application (Citrix QuickEdit) stuck in my iPad's App Store installed by user that used the iPad before me.
There is neither desktop icon of the app, nor it can be found in Settings>General>Storage>Manage Storage (neither local nor cloud storage).

It seems that the app is actually no more on my iPad. There is just a pending update in App Store, for which it asks me for iCloud password of the previous user. It makes me impossible to use "Update all" as it also asks for other user's password and I have to update apps one by one.

Is there any other way of getting rid of the remains of the application than erasing the whole iPad?

I have current iOS 10.1.1 on iPad Air.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Used it before you"? You mean it was never wiped & set up for you as the new owner? That will give you problems in future, as even the iOS itself will be registered to its original owner. See https://support.apple.com/HT201351

Comment: Yes, it was not. I see, but still I wonder if there is a quick solution to this particular problem.

Comment: Not unless you know the password. The app is not yours, so there is nothing you can do with it. In fact the iOS isn't yours, which will cause you massive headaches later.

Comment: Well, there were more apps from the other user that I uninstalled without problem. But as this app has no icon and is not listed in local storage, I cannot do anything with it. Seems more like a bug that left me kinda "ghost" in app store.

Comment: What @Tetsujin is basically saying is that you really should reset your iPad and then set it up as new, otherwise you will have major headaches later. Consider this problem the first headache and an omen of what may come in future. As it is you've already identified two problems since you can't do an Update All either. Time to bite the bullet and do things properly.

Comment: Well, I'm aware of that. Still I wonder if someone has experienced similar problem with "ghost" application and if there is a solution for it.

Comment: I just do not understand the downvotes a bit - in what manner was the question unclear or not useful? I think it is good to know that this may happen and the only proper solution is the full reset. Please be so kind and clarify what is the problem in comments if you downvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while, I agree that factory reset was the only good choice.

Answer (score 0):

If you delete the Office HD 2 app, that will also remove Citrix QuickEdit from the app updating list.

Comment: Thanks but too late to try, I already have reset the ipad